# AsyncResponse throws Exception if not completed within method life time

Tags: java, asynchronous, jersey

I just tried out the example of the Jersey tutorial which concerns `AsyncResponse` and can be found here: http://jersey.java.net/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html

It does not seem to work. Even the example throws an exception when executed in a simple unit test:

```
public class AsyncTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(MyAsync.class)
    }

    @Path("/async")
    public static class MyAsync {
        @GET
        public void asyncGet(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String result = veryExpensiveOperation();
                    asyncResponse.resume(result);
                }

                private String veryExpensiveOperation() {
                    return "bla";
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testConvertWordToPdf() throws Exception {
        String result = target().path("async").request().async().get().get(String.class);
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks for any answer!

**Update**: I even tried the official example that can be found at http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.glassfish.jersey.examples|server-async-standalone-webapp|2.1|war and I get the same exception. The example works, if I make sure the `AsyncResponse` responds before the method returns. The stack trace I get:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
>     at MyCompany.jersey.ConverterResourceTest.testTest(MyClass.java:20)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)    at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:111)
>   Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$1$1.failure(ClientRuntime.java:148)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.internal.InMemoryConnector$3.run(InMemoryConnector.java:265)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:49)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.internal.InMemoryConnector.apply(InMemoryConnector.java:257)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$1.run(ClientRuntime.java:156)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:322)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run(ClientRuntime.java:170)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.KeyComparatorHashMap.putAll(KeyComparatorHashMap.java:509)
>     at
>   javax.ws.rs.core.AbstractMultivaluedMap.putAll(AbstractMultivaluedMap.java:332)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.internal.InMemoryConnector.createClientResponse(InMemoryConnector.java:286)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.internal.InMemoryConnector.apply(InMemoryConnector.java:247)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.internal.InMemoryConnector$3.run(InMemoryConnector.java:261)
>     ... 20 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw, I tested this testcase in Grizzly container. It is not supported in InMemory container as the container does not implement suspend operation on the ContainerResponseWriter. InMemoryResponseWriter should throw an UnsupportedOperationException instead of returning false. This sounds like a Jersey bug.

```
@Test
public void testConvertWordToPdf() throws Exception {
    String result = target().path("async").request().async().get().get().readEntity(String.class);
    assertEquals("bla", result);
}
```

Here is my POM dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The Exception is thrown when requesting the result via get.The request is however still mapped and the resource method is executed. I start to wonder if I should use a different test container. Ill try it tomorrow. Is the example working correctly at your machine?

Comment: Can you send me a pom of your configuration. Im using 2.1 and the inmemory container framework?

Comment: Ok, that makes the difference. I was testing with grizzly container. Here is my dependencies:
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: Thanks, so simple the solution. I never knew that the different containers provided different functionality. I just thought the InMemory container avoided using net traffic by routing any traffic directly within the JVM. Thanks!